# How to query Acive Directory with Windows Powershell for userprincipalname,business phone, and Job Title

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, ldap

Kind of new to scripting here. Currently using the ad module for power shell.  So I want to be able to query the userprincipalname,business phone, and Job Title. Ultimately I'd like to put this onto an excel sheet so I can find those who don't have a phone # or job title. Exporting isn't a huge deal as I can select it out of powershell.

I am able to obtain the name and business phone with the following query

```
Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties OfficePhone | FT OfficePhone,UserPrincipalName
```

I thought it might be as simple as adding Title to the end, however this doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell it that you want to get the title in the first place:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties OfficePhone,Title | FT OfficePhone,UserPrincipalName,Title
```

Comment: The simplest approach is to fetch all properties (`-Properties *`), and then display just the ones you need. However, the downside of this approach is performance, because you'll be fetching *way* more data than you actually need.

Comment: Well, simplest in terms of less typing. That is about it.

Comment: Well, less typing is something I *do* care about in a shell ... ;)

Comment: Aah...in that case -f * -pr * would be even better

Comment: Heh. Indeed it would.